# Binned Number as one hot encoded vector in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, bins

Lets assume I have a DF like below:

| No | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.5 |
| 2 | 34 |
| 3 | 755 |
| 4 | 1203 |
| 5 | 323 |

I want to set a N number of bins (like a histogram) i.e. 5 bins on the "Cost" column, and basically concatenate the One Hot Vectors along with my DataFrame DF like below:

| No | Cost | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 34 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 755 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1203 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 323 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Cost']))`

Comment: Cool this works, but is there a way I can manually set the number of bins?

Comment: pd.cut, then get_dummies

Comment: I did `pd.cut`, then `pd.get_dummies` and finally `pd.concat`. It worked, thanks!